# Is it possible to use google-play-services 7.0 with eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, google-play-services

Latest changes to Google Play Services for Android results in > 65k methods problem in Eclipse. It is possible to include parts of Google Play Services but in Android Studio Only. What about Eclipse? I saw and tried to use some split scripts that split google-play-services.jar but this is not official Google recomendation.

Do they want us to finally migrate to Android Studio?

Comment: "Do they want us to finally migrate to Android Studio?" -- absolutely.